# Use script in the loop to affect the 'read more' button depending on whether a custom field has been used

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I am using the following code in my content.php inside the loop. It's part of the code that is displaying excerpts for my posts. If the user has filled in the 'takeaway' custom field then it produces a second button that takes them to the post but to an anchor as well as the standard 'Read more' option.

In the code is a script that shrinks the standard 'Read more' button down to 50% width using the class .small. This then means that it shrinks down and the second button sits alongside on the same line.
The problem I have is that it adds the class .small to all the 'Read more' buttons, not just the button relevant to that post.

```
<?php $key = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'takeaway', true);    
if($key) : ?> 

<script>
$(".more").addClass("small");
</script>

<a class="takeaway" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#thetakeaway" rel="bookmark">Quick+Dirty!</a>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Is there a way I can make only the relevant 'Read more' button shrink if the custom field of the post has been used, and stay full width if it has not?

Answer (score 1):

The `$(".more")` selects all the read more buttons for sure.

If your takeaway button is placed before read more button, you could do it in just in CSS:

```
.takeaway + .more {
  width: 50%;
}
```

But if the takeaway button is placed after read more button, in jQuery:

```
$(".takeaway").parent().find(".more").addClass("small");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. It is working except - the last instance of .more on the page is not affected? I've tried removing that particular post but again, the last instance does not have the .small attached? Any ideas why not?

Comment: that's weird. what's the generated html for each post? are they the same?

Comment: Yeah, all the same. Except the last instance of .more doesn't have .small attached like all the others do? any ideas? strange...